# Privileges for getting table names from DB2

Tags: php, db2, ibm-midrange

I have 2 servers with same application, should be mirrors (eg. separate hw, separate DB, runs on AS400 i6). Every setting should be the same.
But on one server php function "*db2_ table_ privileges*" (or "*db2_tables either*") returns false (on other server it returns result as expected. (Same code, connection is checked as "*db2_server_info*" returns similar result for both. )
Could anyone tell me which privilege is the culprit, as I think it must be some skipped setting or permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IBM i command to view object authorities is `DSPOBJAUT library/object`, where your table is the object name, the schema is the library, and the type is *FILE.

If the authorities to the schemes might be different,  check `DSPOBJAUT QSYS/library *LIB`, where library is the schema name.

To change authorities, `GRTOBJAUT`, `RVKOBJAUT`, or `EDTOBJAUT`.

You can also query SYSIBM/SQLTABLEPRIVILEGES.